# Tridion Sites MVP 2019?

Tags: discussion

welcome back to real life after the past few weeks of (I hope) good times with friends and family, and over-eating.

As is tradition, we're getting ready for the Tridion Sites MVP selection for 2019, and - as perhaps is tradition too by now - I have been late getting the selection profiles up and running. If you haven't nominated anyone yet, feel free to do so by emailing sdl.tridion.mvp@sdl.com with your choices. We will accept nominations until **Friday January 11th**

Thanks and happy new year!

Comment: The committee members do actively seek out community contributions by nominees, but if nominations are accompanied by a list of hyperlinks that helps a lot to keep it manageable. We are as keen as you are to make sure the results come out on time, so every little helps.

Comment: I have been punctual, did my nomination on 31st Dec itself

Comment: Yes you were. But I wasn't :)

Comment: @NunoLinhares: No Worries, you were covered by the clouds and have to fly across from them to the world :P :D